# 2-D Turbulence - how does it look like?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics, turbulence

Consider parallel flow in the X direction over a 2D semi infinite flat plate. If turbulence is 2-D, in which axes should we expect the vortices to form.
Also, are there any experimental/visualization evidence of 2-D vortical turbulent structures?

Comment: Around the axis which is othogonal to the 2D plate.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433). We expect homework problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. If you edit your question to explain (1) What you have tried, (2) the concept you have trouble with, and (3) your level of understanding, I'll be happy to reopen this. (Flag this message for ♦ attention with a custom message, or reply to me in the comments with `@Manishearth` to notify me)

Comment: @Dilaton i.e. in the Y and Z axes?

Comment: @user2018790 Atmospheric turbulence is experimentally verified to be largely a 2-D Turbulence phenomenon. It does exist.

Comment: @jadelord: Please show your attempt at the problem..

Comment: @user2018790 What you say is not true. In the atmosphere, turbulence with the expected $k^3$ spectrum which can theoretically be explained by a Kolmogorov 2D energy upward and enstrophy forward cascade exists at synoptic scales. It is measured for example by aircraft measurements. Though it is not settled down which turbulence model should be applied, there are alternatives to Kolmogorov 2D such as for example geostrophic turbulence which has the same TKE spectrum too.

Comment: @jadelord in the atmosphere you expect at synopic scales 2D horizontal turbulence due to strong vertical stable stratification of the troposphere at least. If you are interested in such issues the question is maybe not that localized as I thought and you should edit it ?

Comment: @Manishearth please reopen the question. As you might have observed from the other users, it is not a homework problem, but a healthy discussion.

Comment: @jadelord: I'm a bit busy right now, but I've flagged it for the other mods to handle.

Comment: After learning the basic of fluid dynamics you can look into the Annual Review of Fluid Mechanics entitled Two-Dimensional Turbulence (Vol. 44: 427-451). All the answer of your question are in it.

Answer (score 3):

There are many examples of 2D turbulence.  Many experiments involving 2D turbulence use flow in a thin film of soap. 2D turbulence is pretty easy to model too, and I've even seen online web-based examples:
http://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/webgl/gpu/fluid.htm

One super interesting thing about 2D turbulence is the "Inverse energy cascade."  In traditional 3D turbulence big eddies break apart into smaller and smaller eddies:

> Big whirls have little whirls
>   That heed on their velocity, 
>   And little whirls have littler whirls 
>   And so on to viscosity. - L.F. Richardson

in 2D turbulence smaller eddies can and often do combine to form larger eddies.

You may consider reading this article:
http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev-fluid-120710-101240